# Unity 3d (NGUI) How to remember the last scrolled position in the NGUI ScrollView?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollview, ngui

I have a ScrollView with loads of buttons, My question is how to make the scrollview to remember the last scrolled position even after the scene is reloaded. In other words how to make the scroll view to remember the last viewed child so that if the scene is reloaded it should have that particular child in the center of the view. Please ask if you can't get the question

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Scrollbar-value.html Save the value and on scene reload, just set GetComponent<Scrollbar>().value to that value.

Comment: Thanks .. But i found solution before any of you guys answer it . but thanks so much for the answer really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to save the normalized value, `scrollView.horizontalScrollBar.value` or `scrollView.verticalScrollBar.value` whichever applies, to .`xml` or just do a `DontDestroyOnLoad(scrollView.gameObject)`

Answer (score 0):

If you use **`UICenterOnChild`**, simply store the currently centered object (using `centeredObject`) somehow (by index, by name, by whatnot), then do something like `CenterOn(latestCenteredObject.transform)` when loaded.

See [`UICenterOnChild` docs](http://www.tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_center_on_child.html) for more.